# Dual boot ubuntu only loads in terminal mode after deleting Python

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, python, 20.04

I have a dual boot through **grub**. Windows 10 is the default and Ubuntu is the other login. I upgraded to **Ubuntu 20.04** early after ignoring all the warnings and most things were fine but I've been having the odd issue. AWS EB CLI had stopped working because it was saying the datetime util was missing, in fact, it was installed for Python 3.8, not the version it uses (3.7). I ended up deleting **Python 3.8** entirely and installing it for 3.7. After this, I am unable to login to the Ubuntu GUI. When I select Ubuntu on the grub instead of going to the GUI I go straight to a terminal to login. As far as I've noticed it works normally, but the GUI won't start up, not even with `startx`.

I don't mind deleting everything and starting over, unless anyone has any ideas for a better way. What is the best thing to do here? Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: 19.10 uses Python 3.7, but 20.04 uses Python 3.8. Seems like you deleted the wrong version of Python.

Comment: I'm thinking to download the iso, put it on a USB stick, boot it from BIOS and repair the installation. It's a dual boot and I don't want to delete Windows 10. Should this work? Anything to avoid?

Comment: You can certainly repair that way if you are skilled at using a chroot. A data backup before starting is always wise.